# List all categories with featured image from post?

Tags: posts, categories, images, list

With this code I show all categories:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br />';
}
?>
```

I want to show all categories with featured image, load featured image from post, example:

Category Tours, first post: my first travel / with featured image

Load image from my first travel in / Category Tours
can be load from first post or last post or aleatory this is not important, but have to be from any post.

I can do this with plugin featured image category
with the code below, I list all categories with featured image, but I have to set independently image to category, but I not want to use plugin.

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
  );
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 

    echo '<img src="' . cfi_featured_image_url( array( 'cat_id' => $category->term_id, 'size' => 'full' ) ) . '">';
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  }
?>
```

Thanks for reading.